# Having trouble installing archived packages for R 3.6.0

Tags: r

I can't seem to find a work around to install old packages archived. 
I am currently using this

```
install.packages("https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RGtk2Extras/RGtk2Extras_0.6.1.tar.gz",
                 repos=NULL, method="libcurl")
```

However get a

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Daimen/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RGtk2Extras/RGtk2Extras_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content length 88734 bytes (86 KB)
downloaded 86 KB

* installing *source* package 'RGtk2Extras' ...
** package 'RGtk2Extras' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RGtk2Extras'
* removing 'C:/Users/Daimen/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/RGtk2Extras'
Warning message:
In install.packages("https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RGtk2Extras/RGtk2Extras_0.6.1.tar.gz",  :
installation of package 
In install.packages("https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RGtk2Extras/RGtk2Extras_0.6.1.tar.gz",  :
installation of package 
‘C:/Users/Daimen/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMXJ3Pi/downloaded_packages
/RGtk2Extras_0.6.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've tried to install this by means of downloading and importing it locally.. Still same error. I understand that this package is not available for this particular version of R however; is there a work around for this?

Comment: Do you have RTools installed and on your system path? It's not a package, it's an accompanying download that will give you the compilers needed to build packages that use C or C++ code from source

Comment: Hi Gregor, I tried installing RTools via install.packages("RTools") and i get package ‘RTools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Daimen [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html)  is not an R package, you'll need to install it with installer.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! Can now do my uni assignment!